# How to solve it. error:Error in data[[rowvar]] : attempt to select less than one element

Tags: r

In order to simplify my question, I will first show an example of a data file.

**Data file:**

```
clo1  clo2    clo3
1     2       3
1     2       3
5     6       7
```

**R code:**

```
read.table("demo.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = "a")
```

**Output:**

```
  
> Error in data[[rowvar]] : attempt to select less than one element
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '../demo.txt'
```

Comment: yes. I just follow the book's demo. I don't understand what its destination.

Comment: I don't know which book your are reading. I was referring to the documentation of the `read.table` function in `help("read.table")`.

Comment: Doing Data Sciences. I know what you infer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by row.names = "a". Data set must have different row names. If you try to name all rows "a", you get the error. If you have a vector which contains the row names you want to use, you can do this.

```
> a <- c("A", "B", "C")
> read.table("demo.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = a)
  clo1 clo2 clo3
A    1    2    3
B    1    2    3
C    5    6    7
```

Comment: Thank you. But I've tried this method. Because it's the demo of my book, i just wanna make sure what led this error. Now, i know it is  the book's mistake.

Comment: This answer in wrong! row.names can also be the name of one column, if you tried "clo1" for example it would have worked

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), row.names is:

> a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the actual row
>   names, or a single number giving the column of the table which
>   contains the row names, or character string giving the name of the
>   table column containing the row names.
>
> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than
>   the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the
>   row names. Otherwise if row.names is missing, the rows are numbered.
>
> Using row.names = NULL forces row numbering. Missing or NULL row.names
>   generate row names that are considered to be ‘automatic’ (and not
>   preserved by as.matrix).

So you can provide either the name of a column (like "clo1" in your example), or a vector of names for each row (as Patrick Li pointed out). I think your book was correct.